# How to define the type of Column (like Hyperlink) when binding a list of objects?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have a object defined like this

```
public class BizObject
{
    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";

    [DisplayName("Size")]
    public UInt32 Size { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Value")]
    public Byte Value { get; set; }
}
```

And populate DGV like this:

```
List<BizObject> myData = new List<BizObject>()
{
    new BizObject {Name = "John" },
    new BizObject {Name = "Arthur" },
    new BizObject {Name = "Clark" },
};

dgvTest.Columns.Clear();
dgvTest.DataSource = myData;

dgvTest.Columns["Name"].ValueType = typeof(DataGridViewLinkColumn); // not working
```

Note: I have > 100k rows in my application (ie. objects)

I try to have hyperlinks for entire column, based on cell value, opening some local executable.

Now I could a `Click` event on a Cell, get Cell and do whatever I want.
Probably I could also format column to look like a hyperlink.

But I noticed that columns can have also other types, like `DataGridViewLinkColumn`.

Since I use DataSource to get list of objects, my column types are determined automatically (like string, bool, int).

I can't figure out (or if it's possible) how to convince DGV to use another type when bind to a object collection, without defining the columns manually.

Something like this:

```
public class BizObject
{
    [DisplayName("Name"), ColumnType=typeof(DataGridViewLinkColumn)] 
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";

    [DisplayName("Size")]
    public UInt32 Size { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Value")]
    public Byte Value { get; set; }
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: I am guessing you may have to add the column manually, similar to a combo box column. Is there some reason adding the column manually is an issue, I mean, it would not be a lot of code to add a link column?

Comment: Add `dgvTest.AutoGenerateColumns = false;` and add the Columns before you set the DataSource, specifying the `DataPropertyName` for each. -- `ValueType` describes the Type of the Column's content, not the DataGridViewColumn class.

Comment: BTW, if you want to use Attributes to specify how to use the class Properties in a DataGridView, you need to add a reference to `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and decorate the class with an appropriate `TypeDescriptionProvider`.